# Solving simultaneous partial differential equations (first-order)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve the simultaneous equations (1 and 2) for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. I have never seen an example like this, what is the method!?

$$\begin{cases} x \frac{∂f}{∂y} - y \frac{∂f}{∂x} + g = 0 \; ,\\ x \frac{∂g}{∂y} - y \frac{∂g}{∂x} - f = 0 \; .\end{cases}$$

Comment: Have you ever solved algebraic systems of equations? In particular linear systems of equations over the reals?

Comment: Yes, I have done. Am I being stupid, or can I just substitute in f into equation 1 and then solve for g!?

Comment: That's exactly what I was alluding to.

Comment: You can use the method of characteristics. If you are able to find the Riemann invariant of this system you will be able to solve the system. Substitution is also possible but the resulting pde is not easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases} x \frac{∂f}{∂y} - y \frac{∂f}{∂x} + g = 0 \; ,\\ x \frac{∂g}{∂y} - y \frac{∂g}{∂x} - f = 0 \; .\end{cases}$$
The change of Cartesian system of coordinates to polar :$\quad\begin{cases}x=\rho\cos(\theta)\\y=\rho\sin(\theta)\end{cases}$

leads to a very simple system :
$$\begin{cases}\frac{∂f}{∂\theta}+g=0\\ \frac{∂g}{∂\theta}-f=0\end{cases}\quad\to\quad \frac{∂^2f}{∂\theta^2}+f=0$$
$$\begin{cases}f=c_1(\rho)\cos(\theta)+c_2(\rho)\sin(\theta)\\g=-\frac{∂f}{∂\theta}=c_1(\rho)\sin(\theta)-c_2(\rho)\cos(\theta)\end{cases}$$

$\frac{c_1(\rho)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\frac{c_2(\rho)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ can be considered as arbitrary functions of $\rho$, say $F(\rho)$ and $G(\rho)$.

Back to Cartesian coordinates : 
$$\begin{cases}f(x,y)=x\:F(x^2+y^2)+y\:G(x^2+y^2)\\g(x,y)=y\:F(x^2+y^2)-x\:G(x^2+y^2)\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can't the coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ depend on $r$? I think they have to, because otherwise your solution doesn't capture the following solution: $f=ax+by$ and $g=-bx+ay$.

Comment: You are right : in the integrations vs $\theta$, the arbitrary parameters are functions of $\rho$. I will correct my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that is shorter than the one below, applying the method of characteristics directly to the problem as stated.

Introduce $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ such that $dx/dt=-y$ and $dy/dt=x$. Then the equations become

$$\begin{cases} \frac{df}{dt} + g = 0 \; ,\\ \frac{dg}{dt} - f = 0 \; .\end{cases}$$

The four equations can be solved to give

$$\begin{cases} x=a\cos t + b \sin t  \; ,\\ y=a\sin t - b \cos t \; ,\\  f=A\cos t + B \sin t  \; ,\\ g=A\sin t - B \cos t \; .\end{cases}$$

Set the initial conditions to $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=0$, $f(0)=u(x_0)$ and $g(0)=v(x_0)$. Then we have

$$\begin{cases} x=x_0\cos t  \; ,\\ y=x_0\sin t \; ,\\  f=u(x_0)\cos t + v(x_0) \sin t  \; ,\\ g=u(x_0)\sin t - v(x_0) \cos t \; .\end{cases}$$

But $x_0=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, thus we can rewrite the solutions as

$$\begin{cases} f=u(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + v(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  \; ,\\ g=u(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} - v(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \; .\end{cases}$$

---

Solution using the hints in the comments. First let's introduce a new notation for the differential operator

$$H:=x \frac{∂}{∂y} - y \frac{∂}{∂x} \; .$$

The equations then become

$$\begin{cases} Hf + g = 0 \; ,\\ Hg - f = 0 \; .\end{cases}$$

Substituting the last equation in the first, we get an equation for $g$ only

$$H^2g+g=0 \; ,$$

which we can rewrite as

$$(H+i)(H-i)g=0$$

So the general solution for $g$ will be a linear combination of solutions for

$$(H+i)g=0 \;\; \text{ and } \;\; (H-i)g=0$$

Let's focus our attention on the last one, the other one can be solved similarly. Let's also introduce a new variable $z=\ln(g)$, then the last equation is

$$x \frac{∂z}{∂y} - y \frac{∂z}{∂x} = i$$

We can now easily apply the method of characteristics, put

$$\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt}=-y \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=x \\ \frac{dz}{dt}=i\end{cases}$$

The general solutions being

$$\begin{cases}x(t)=A\cos t + B \sin t \\ y(t) = A\sin t - B \cos t \\ z(x(t),t)=it+C\end{cases}$$

We now put as initial conditions $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=0$ and $z(x_0,0)=u(x_0)$. This means

$$\begin{cases}x(t)=x_0\cos t \\ y(t) = x_0\sin t \\ z(x(t),t)=it+u(x_0)\end{cases}$$

Restating that last part in terms of $g$ and introducing $v(x)=\exp{u(x)}$:

$$\begin{cases}x(t)=x_0\cos t \\ y(t) = x_0\sin t \\ g(x(t),t)=v(x_0)e^{it}\end{cases}$$

We can find out of the first equation that $x_0=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and thus write

$$g(x,y)=v\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\frac{x+iy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Solving the other equation $(H+i)g=0$, it is clear we'll get a complex conjugate of the one we just solved, which means we can always express the complete solution $g$ as a real function

$$g(x,y)=v\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\frac{b_1 x+b_2 y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Filling this in the remaining equation

$$x \frac{∂g}{∂y} - y \frac{∂g}{∂x} - f = 0$$

We can find the formula for $f$

$$f(x,y)=v\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\frac{b_2 x-b_1 y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Also, we can group the factors with the square root in just one function $w\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=v\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, obviously.

Comment: In the first method, how do we know that we have to set y(0) = 0. Why can this be assumed?

Comment: What you do in the method of characteristics is to look at the solution of your system as representing a surface $(x,y,f(x,y),g(x,y))$ in 4D. Then, you notice that you can rewrite your equations as $$(-y,x,-g,f)\cdot(\partial_x f, \partial_y f, -1 , 0)=0$$ and $$(-y,x,-g,f)\cdot(\partial_x g, \partial_y g, 0 , -1)=0$$. But the last vector in each scalar product is actually a normal vector of that surface. So, you introduce a set of curves lying in that surface, by setting $(dx/dt,dy/dt,df/dt,dg/dt)=(-y,x,-g,f)$. Indeed,this says the curves' tangent vectors are orthogonal to the normal vectors.

Comment: Now, the thing is, you can pick many different sets of such curves to characterize your surface. You pick a specific initial condition, such that the problem will be easier to solve. I could just as well have picked $x(0)=0$. The important part is that your complete set of curves characterizes your surface entirely. However, it is not straightforward that this is always possible. [Here's some further reading about the method.](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf)

Comment: The criterium for the choice of initial conditions, is that the curve represented by those initial conditions is non-characteristic. The definition and examples are given in the reference. You can check that this works out for the present exercise. (But you can't set both $x(0)$ and $y(0)$ equal to $0$ for example.)

Comment: Ahh yes of course, as we are solving for f and g we can basically set x(0) and y(0) to be whatever we like. Thanks very much.